# Быстрый способ сравнения больших массивов строк

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, строки

В-общем задача у меня такая: 
есть два больших массива слов, которые нужно сравнить между собой. один порядка пары сотен тысяч, и другой где-то приблизительно столько же.
Метод последовательного сравнения не подходит, т.к. займет очень много времени, нужно что-то куда более быстрое.
Какие наиболее быстродействующие алгоритмы (алгоритм) вы можете порекомендовать?
Нужно срочно.
Спасибо.
P.S. Речь идет не об сравнении коллекций, а о нахождении вхождений срок.
Котик, под "порогом в 0.8" понимается что сравниваться должен только корень слова, без окончания. Либо же как-то привести слово к его первоначальной, инфинитивнойпервоначальной форме, что я вообще пока не представляю как сделать.

Comment: Многопоточность?

Comment: не-не-не, все в одном потоке

Comment: не знаю, деревья какие-нибудь, мне нужен самый быстрый.

Comment: Не, я говорю: производить параллельную обработку строк. Разбить, к примеру, строки на несколько кусков и каждый обрабатывать в отдельном потоке. Для этого, конечно, требуется многоядерный процессор. Можно использовать какой-нибудь фреймворк, типа OpenMP

Comment: Кстати, а в чем именно заключается сравнение? Что нужно получить?

Comment: Тут нужно именно на одном процессоре.

Comment: И еще: какой язык?

Comment: Смотрите, есть файл с текстом какого-то произведения, большого, ну скажем, Достоевского "Бесы" (пара мегабайт чистого ASCII текста). Есть также словарь, русско-английский, на 15 тысяч слов. Нужно в выходной файл, записать те слова, что встречаются в словаре, и есть одновременно в тексте, при этом порог, достаточный для совпадения, равен 0.8, т.е. не все слово, а только какая-то его часть. 
Я сделал очень глупо: создал два контейнера, списка, загрузил в них из файлов все их содержимое, а затем тупо во вложенном цикле сравнивал каждый с каждым, и совпадения выносил в отдельный словарь.

Comment: Язык С++. Вся беда в том, что на анализ одного текста (большого) уходит от 5 до 8 минут, а мне нужно проанализировать 150 текстов до завтрашнего утра. (150*8 )/ 60 = 17 часов, что означает что я никак не успеваю. Процессор у меня одноядерный кстати.

Comment: Подробнее напишите про "порог для совпадения 0.8". От этого, по сути, зависит правильное решение. И вынесите ваш комментарий в первоначальный вопрос, потому что вы спросили про **сравнение коллекций,** а, как оказывается, вам нужно **искать вхождения слов.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод первый. Сортируем оба массива. Потом в один проход проходим оба массива и сравниваем поэлементно (это не сравнение куча на кучу, так как массивы отсортированы, то поиск будет очень быстрый - нужно просто сдвинуть "виртуальный курсор" на пару элементов вперед).

Метод второй. Придумываем хеш функцию, которая бы строку преобразовывала в 2 байта (это может просто быть сумма аски кодов символов с сдвигом).
Заводим 2 массива размерности 2^16 и для каждое слово (индекс в большом массиве) добавляем в соответствующую ячейку.  Одинаковые слова в разные ячейки не попадут, поэтому достаточно будет пробежаться по словам в одной ячейке.

Comment: уже сортированы, оба массива находятся в контейнерах и обработаны .sort() и .unique(), что кстати заметно ускорило время обработки, но все равно оно еще остается очень долгим. о хешировании думал но совершенно не представляю как его использовать (это кстати и первая идея была, я пытался мутить с Crc но так и оставил эту идею в силу недопонимания некоторых параметров хеширования последней).

Comment: мне вот интересно, можно ли как-то вообще избежать полных переборов, даже с использованием хеш-функций, типа как в двоичных деревьях, что за 5-10 выборок можно добраться до целевого элемента. ох бы как увеличило это время выборки!

Comment: Посмотрите на сортировку слиянием. И на картинки тут http://sashkoblog.blogspot.com/2008/11/blog-post_16.html
Ваша задача в принципе ничем не отличается, разве что массив в результате получить не нужно.
То есть, всего навсего будет один цикл и два "индекса".

Comment: Так мне и "сливать" не нужно вроде как.

Comment: Да нет, не отбросить. Что получится быстрее, то и возьму.

Answer (score 1):

Если, как оказалось, нужно искать русские слова из произвольного реального текста в словаре, то это задача очень сложная, поскольку в русском языке в разных грамматических формах происходит изменение окончания слова, изменения в корне, суффиксе и т.д. И все это надо учитывать, если вести подсчет именно по смыслу слова.

А так - можно ускорить поиск слова в словаре, применяя, например, бинарный поиск.

Comment: да, я тоже пришел к данному выводу. тем не менее программа нужна на завтра, так что...

Comment: Мда... Боюсь, что на раз-два такую штуку не написать... Но если забыть про сложности русской грамматики, то вот - бинарный поиск (алгоритм STL binary_search). Можно еще организовать словарь в виде дерева (можно использовать set).

Comment: mikillsegg, спасибо вам большое за помощь, а можете еще что-нибудь на счет хеш функции посоветовать? какой она должна быть? (это я чтобы ускорить двоичный поиск).

Comment: Если компилятор поддерживает С++11, то можно воспользоваться новым контейнером unorderуd_set. Или же посмотреть на библиотеку Boost.Unordered.

Comment: Откровенно не понимаю. 

Если есть отсортированный словарь их 15000 слов, то двоичный поиск в нем должен работать **очень** быстро. 14 сравнений, если не ошибаюсь. 

Если считать, что одно сравнение займет 1000 команд (на самом деле д.б. меньше), то на поиск слова понадобится (для 1Ghz) что-то вроде 14 мкс. На  500000 слов (с избытком, на деле их меньше) в файле 7 секунд. 

Куда остальное время (5 минут = 300 сек) уходит ???

Comment: Видимо на добавление в какой-нибудь вектор. Или сохранение в файл. Был бы код - могли бы и профайлером пробежать.

Comment: Так человек, похоже, не пользовался двоичным поиском.